# Using SASS how do I pass more than two arguments using map-get?

Tags: sass

I have a color map that looks like this:

```
  $colors: (
    brand-blue: (
        lightest: #87B9D9,
        lighter: #3395D4,
        light: #0370B7,
        base: #232D4B,
    )
  )
```

I'm trying to call a specific color using "map-get"

```
#foo {
  border: 1px solid map-get($colors, brand-blue, base);
}
```

I'm getting errors that I can't call more that two arguments. What am I doing wrong? Or, more importantly is there something I can do differently?

Thanks

Comment: It's working fine for me. Giving me this `#foo { border: 1px solid #232d4b;}` as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#get):

> Only Dart Sass supports calling `map.get()` with more than two arguments.

If you're not using Dart Sass, you can use a helper function such as [this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/#aa-deep-get) to create your own `map-get` with multiple keys support:

```scss
@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
   @each $key in $keys {
      $map: map-get($map, $key);
   }
   @return $map;
}
```

```scss
#foo {
  border: 1px solid map-deep-get($colors, brand-blue, base);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
map-get($colors, "brand-blue", "base")
```